# Swift Firebase How to Swipe to Delete Messages in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

please How to Swipe to Delete Messages in TableView ?

**Data From Firebase:**

[image: data from firebase]

```
 var sectionsArray = [NSDictionary?]()
```

Code super.viewDidLoad()

```
      databaseRef.child("Sections").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        var key = snapshot.key
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: key)


            self. sectionsArray.append(snapshot)

            self.TableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self. sectionsArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }


    }
```

Code Delete

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

       // I want this code...

    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but the general concept is you get the index of the swiped row and then remove that row from your dataSource array, then reload your tableView. Keeping in mind that will not remove the data from Firebase. There are about 100 different ways to do this task so I don't think there is any one answer.

Comment: Yes, my friend, this is what I want And Delete data from Firebase

Comment: Great! So what's the issue? I assume you know how to read the row from the array, which means you also have the key to the snapshot node (snapshot.key), which means you can then delete the row from the array and remove that node, via the key, from Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for finding the solution ❤︎